# How to Enable AjaxValidtion for Specific Filed in yii2

Tags: yii2

I Have Following Field Only Put Ajax Valiadtion

```
     <?= 
        $form->field($questionModel, 
       'questions_options_order')->dropDownList(Yii::$app->controller->optionsOrderArr 
      , ['class' => 'form-control required']) 
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Model rulse

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
        [['questions_options_order'], 'required'], 
       ];
    }
```

> View look like this

```
<?= 
        $form->field($questionModel, 
       'questions_options_order')->dropDownList(Yii::$app->controller->optionsOrderArr 
      , ['prompt' => 'Select options Type']) 
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
> Put Enable Ajaxvalidation true specific filed
 <?=
       $form->field($oModel, 'variable_file',['enableAjaxValidation' => false])->widget(FileInput::classname(), [
       'options'       => ['accept' => 'csv', 'class' => 'required file_input'],
       'pluginOptions' => ['allowedFileExtensions' => ['csv']]
         ]);
    ?>
```